# TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I do not understand what is the problem writing in last row.
extend1 is function inside a dictionary dispatch

```
def make_mutable_rlist(ctor=None):
    """Return a functional implementation of a mutable recursive list"""
    contents = empty_rlist
    if ctor != None:
        i=ctor['length']()-1
        print (i)
        while i >=0:
            contents = make_rlist(ctor['get_item'](i),contents)
            i-=1
    def length():
        return len_rlist(contents)
    def get_item(index):
        return getitem_rlist(contents,index)
    def push_first(value):
        nonlocal contents
        contents = make_rlist(value,contents)

    def extend1(mutable_list):
        nonlocal contents
        len1 = length()-1
        len2 = mutable_list['length']()
        for i in range (len1,len1+len2):
            contents['push_first'](mutable_list['get_item'](i))
```

Comment: what's about the 2nd line: `nonlocal contents`?

Comment: contents defined in another function up than extended1 @RuhulAmin

Comment: then add that function in the code so that we can inspect

Comment: Update @RuhulAmin

Comment: `contents['push_first'][(mutable_list['get_item'](i))]` try this

Comment: I get the same error @RuhulAmin

Comment: Sorry. how mutable list `mutable_list['get_item'][i]`

Comment: The same error , i update the code @RuhulAmin

Comment: How are you calling your function, and what is the exact error you are getting (along with the traceback)?

Comment: Can you add the full error message to the question. All the error is that you have a function name and are calling it as `func[...]` instead of `func(...)` wrong brackets. So the error message should point to which line is incorrectly calling a function.